# Discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need help with discord bot in **python**.
I need a bot to ***save every message send to it via dm***

I tried this but it only saved time and numbers of messages, not it content

```py
async def update_stats():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    global messages

    while not bot.is_closed():
        try:
            with open("stats.txt", "a") as f: 
                f.write(f"Czas: {int(time.time())},Wiad: {messages}\n")
        
            messages = 0
            await asyncio.sleep (30)
        except Exception as e 
            print (e)
            await asyncio.sleep (30)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global messages
    messages += 1
    
bot.loop.create_task(update_stats())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is totally valid, as you only save the number of messages. You should save the messages too.

Not tested code (I don't have the full environment for a bot now):

```py
messages = 0
messages_list = list()

async def update_stats():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    while not bot.is_closed():
        try:
            with open("stats.txt", "a") as f: 
                f.write(f"Czas: {int(time.time())}\n")
                f.write("Messages:\n")
                for message in messages_list:
                    f.write(message)
                messages_list.clear()
            messages = 0
            await asyncio.sleep (30)
        except Exception as e 
            print (e)
            await asyncio.sleep (30)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    messages += 1
    messages_list.append(message)
    
bot.loop.create_task(update_stats())
```

However, if you want to save the messages when they arrive, you can only write a more simple function:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("stats.txt", "a") as f: 
        f.write(f"Czas: {int(time.time())}\n")
        f.write("New message:\n")
        f.write(message)
```

Another edit: As I recalled, the bot does not only get the message in raw format, but an object with the "context" of the message, so the function should look like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == message.author.dm_channel.id:
        with open("stats.txt", "a") as f: 
            f.write(f"Czas: {int(time.time())}\n")
            f.write("New message:\n")
            f.write(message.content)
```